# #icon:hover + #text transition for + #text part

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the icon text should appear, so far so good, however I want it to smoothly transition into view. I can't seem to find a way to do that.

```css
#vegicon {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

#vegicontext {
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

#vegicon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px darkgray;
}

#vegicon:hover+#vegicontext {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span id="vegicon"><i class="fas fa-seedling"></i></span>
<span id="vegicontext">Veggy</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot animate the `display` property, but you can animate `opacity`.

Also, you need to add `transition` for the animation, such as `transition: opacity .5s ease-in;`

```css
#vegicon{
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

#vegicontext{
  opacity:0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-left: 1px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

#vegicon:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px darkgray;
}

#vegicon:hover + #vegicontext{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

 <span id="vegicon"><i class="fas fa-seedling"></i></span>
<span id="vegicontext">Veggy</span>
```

You could also animated the `max-width` property, but make sure your `max-width` is not less than the widest element you're animating:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
}

.vegicon{
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.vegicontext{
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-left: 2px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

.vegicon:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px darkgray;
}

.vegicon:hover + .vegicontext {
  opacity: 1;
  /* this may need to be changed depending on the max length of your text */
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <span class="vegicon"><i class="fas fa-seedling"></i></span>
    <div class="vegicontext">Veggy</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-container">
    <span class="vegicon"><i class="fas fa-seedling"></i></span>
    <div class="vegicontext">Veggy</div>
  </div>
   <div class="icon-container">
    <span class="vegicon"><i class="fas fa-seedling"></i></span>
    <div class="vegicontext">Veggy</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Though the reason I used display and not opacity is because there is another icon next to it, which ideally should be able to move to the side and collapse to again. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I can help you in a little bit. But try to play with it remembering all the properties that you can use "transition" on.

Comment: I added another snippet that gives an example of animating the `max-width` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I played around with it a bit and it works perfectly now :)